Unable to retrieve parent list fields when using CAML join query and sharepoint online
I am trying to use caml join queries when querying data from sharepoint through the webapi and Power Automate (HTTP send)?
Is it possible to retrieve fields from the parent list through projectedfields, I can join and return fields from the child list but not the parent. Have been playing with this for sometime but no joy. I am wondering if this only works at all on the web api. Below is a representation of my script: Nomination Detail is the child list with a lookup to the parent list (Nominations) using column 'Nomination'. I want to show the NominationDate from the parent list, so I created a projectedfield and added it to the viewfields. But it will only show fields from the child list. Any guidance greatly appreciated.
_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Nomination Detail')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1=
{"ViewXml":"
<View>
    <ViewFields>
        <FieldRef Name='ID'/>
        <FieldRef Name='YearOfService'/>
                <FieldRef Name='NominationDate'/>       
                <FieldRef Name='Nomination'/>
    </ViewFields>
    <Joins>
        <Join Type='INNER' ListAlias='Nominations'>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Nomination' RefType='Id'/>
                <FieldRef Name='ID' List='Nominations'/>
            </Eq>
        </Join>
    </Joins>
<ProjectedFields>
    <Field Name='NominationDate' Type='Lookup' List='Nominations' ShowField='NominationDate'/>
</ProjectedFields>
</View> 
"}


Any reason you are using CAML query and HTTP action instead of "Get items" action? Or why not using GET /items method?

My solution has a number of related lists and it would have been useful if I could have joined these in in one call. I have abandoned CAML now as I couldn't get it to work and gone with GET /items and instead use multiple calls. Thanks for your response.
